# How to preserve and access processing instructions in MSXML IXMLDOMDocument2

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, delphi-2010, msxml

I have this problem, that I need to access processing instruction in MSXML IXMLDOMDocument2 interface.
Is it possible to do `XMLDocument.load()` and have access to `xml-stylesheet` instruction?
If it is, how to do it right?

I have xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
...
```

and I need to extract `xml-stylesheet` `href` value.
But `XMLDocument` seems to not contain this processing instruction after `XMLDocument.load()` operation.
So than I can't perform:

```
XMLDocument.transformNode(XSLDocument);
```

with `XSLDocument` being filled with what is inside `transform.xsl`, because I don't know where `transform.xsl` is being located.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what have you tried that you think "But XMLDocument seems to not contain this processing instruction after XMLDocument.load() operation"? I would think that XMLDocument.childNodes contains that processing instruction, I don't remember whether Microsoft put the XML declaration in the DOM or not, if not, XMLDocument.firstChild.data should give you the `type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"` value I think.

Comment: `XMLDocument.selectSingleNode("processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')").data` should also work if XPath is used as the selection language (i.e. by default in MSXML 6 or by setting it first with MSXML 3 `XMLDocument.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")`.

Comment: Using `XMLDocument.documentElement` when I search for it, there is none of such element.

Comment: I don't understand the reference to `documentElement`, that would give you the root element of the XML e.g. for `<root><foo>...</foo></root>` the `root` element, for e.g. `<html><body>...</body></html>` the `html` element node. That `xml-stylesheet` sits before the root element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - oh yes, Your absolutely right, It seams that I'm tired after whole day of working on this. Thanks, put Your answer below please, so I can check it as solution.

Comment: This `XMLDocument.selectSingleNode("processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')")` looks even more interesting than XMLDocument.childNodes enumeration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming MSXML doesn't model the XML declaration as a node (I don't think it does but I am not sure) you should be able to access the processing instruction as `XMLDocument.firstChild` and `XMLDocument.firstChild.data` gives you then the "value" of the processing instruction, i.e. the complete string `type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"`.

You should also be able to select the node using XPath and `XMLDocument.selectSingleNode("processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')").data`, only XPath is not the default selection language in MSXML 3 (only in MSXML 6) so for MSXML 3 you would need to first set `XMLDocument.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")`.

Comment: One addition, after testing this, it seems that field `data` not exists in `Delphi 2010` implementation of MSXML, but field `nodeValue` contains all I need, i.e.: XMLDocument.firstChild.nodeValue returns all attributes.